# Composer cannot connect to internet (github)

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, composer-php

Im trying to update composer and install new project but composer could not connect to internet. getting error "The

```
"https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: failed  
   to open stream: Connection timed out "
```

OS : ubuntu 16.04

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: What is the output of: wget https://getcomposer.org/versions:

Comment: Ps: add https:// in front of getcomposer. Stackoverflow made it a link (on mobile)

Comment: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4142

Comment: wget out put:

wget getcomposer.org/versions
--2016-11-10 07:48:33--  http://getcomposer.org/versions
Resolving getcomposer.org (getcomposer.org)... 2001:41d0:a:7b19::2, 87.98.253.108
Connecting to getcomposer.org (getcomposer.org)|2001:41d0:a:7b19::2|:80...

Comment: Thank you for every one. i have fixed this using follwing command.

sudo sh -c "echo 'precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100' >> /etc/gai.conf"

Comment: kiran@kiran-Inspiron-5379:/var/www/REPO/ucaz$ wget getcomposer.org/versions 
--2018-10-19 11:06:06--  http://getcomposer.org/versions
Resolving getcomposer.org (getcomposer.org)... 2001:41d0:302:1100::8:104f
Connecting to getcomposer.org (getcomposer.org)|2001:41d0:302:1100::8:104f|:80... failed: Network is unreachable.